# Which US naval ship from 1905 is depicted on this photo?

Tags: united-states, identification, naval, ships

[image: U.S. warship photo taken around 1900, location: could be Hudson River, NY]

I found this photo in a relatives old photo collection. Most of the photos were taken around 1905 so I assume the ship photo was taken around that time. A lot of the photos were taken in upstate NY around the Hudson River Valley.

Comment: Well, that's definitely a US flag.

Comment: Looking at the pages  linked off of
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cruisers_of_the_United_States_Navy#Armored_Cruisers  , it looks like a "Pennsylvania" or "Tennessee" class armored cruiser (ACR-4 thru ACR-9, and ACR-10 thru ACR-14, respectively). The 4 stacks are distinctive, but the quality of photos (yours and Wikipedia's) is too poor for me to make a precise match.

Comment: ...Or maybe a scout cruiser of the St Louis class, as illustrated on http://www.navsource.org/archives/04/c20/c20.htm and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_St._Louis_(C-20) .

Comment: @kimchilover, not a *St Louis*: the pictured ship has a twin turret in the front, which the *Pennsylvania* and *Tennessee* classes have, but the *St Louis* doesn't.

Comment: @Mark Maybe: my eyes are bad.  By "front" do you mean the end at the left, closest to the photographer?  I read that as the stern.

Comment: @kimchilover, yes, the end nearest the photographer.

Comment: I agree with @Kimchi: The ship is sailing away from us.

Answer (score 12):

It's a stern view of a [*Pennsylvania*-class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pennsylvania-class_cruiser) or [*Tennessee*-class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennessee-class_cruiser) armored cruiser, photographed sometime prior to 1912.  Distinguishing features:

- An American flag.
- Four stacks.  Most early US Navy cruisers had one to three stacks.
- A twin-gun turret.  This distinguishes it from the [*St. Louis*-class cruisers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Louis-class_cruiser_(1905)), which had only only casemate guns, and from the [*Columbia*-class cruisers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columbia-class_cruiser), which had single-gun turrets.
- Solid masts.  In the 1911-1912 timeframe, the *Pennsylvania* and *Tennessee* cruisers were refitted with [lattice masts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_mast) to reduce weight.

If the photograph is from 1905, then the ship is one of [USS *Pennsylvania*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Pennsylvania_(ACR-4)), [USS *West Virginia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_West_Virginia_(ACR-5)), [USS *Colorado*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Colorado_(ACR-7)), or [USS *Maryland*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Maryland_(ACR-8)), as the other ships of those two classes were commissioned in the 1906-1908 timeframe.  There's a decent chance that it's the USS *West Virginia*, since that ship served with the [New York Naval Militia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_Naval_Militia).

Comment: Although it's impossible to make out the actual letters in the ship's name painted on the stern, they do extend for quite a long way and put me in the mind of "INIA".

Comment: The masts, lifeboat arrangement, and stern porthole arrangement all appear to match the *Pennsylvania-class* cruisers much better than the *Tennessee-class* cruisers.

Comment: Agreed, Pieter.  Looking at my trusty 1905 Janes, this ship is assuredly one of the Pennsylvania class.

Answer (score 1):

An attempt at an answer as a guest, because I do not have an account, so cannot comment, and may have spotted a couple details in passing.

Feel free to delete this answer and just add to Mark's

Mark as provided the evidence for a Pennsylvania or Tennessee class cruiser. On Wikipedia, the picture for the [Pennsylvania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pennsylvania-class_cruiser#/media/File:USS_Pennsylvania_(CA-4).jpg) shows 4 [casemate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casemate) guns on the upper deck, and the picture for the [Tennessee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennessee-class_cruiser#/media/File:USSNorthCarolinaACR12.jpg) 5 casemate guns.

The ship in the question as 4 casemate guns on her upper deck, not 5.
Also, the difference in hue between the hull and the upper works would match the colors on the Pennsylvania picture.

Therefore, I would wager she is a Pennsylvania class, not a Tennessee.